# password protect core data persistent store

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data

Is there a way to password protect the SQL Lite db core data uses for it's persistent store?  I want to make the DB available via iTunes but I want to be password protected so only I can open it.

Comment: just asking, if you are the onlyOne that can open it. why do you want it available in itunes?

Comment: This is an internal B2B app and will contain some sensitive information, if the end user has a problem I can have them send me the file to retrieve the info out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreData doesnt have any built in password protection so you are going to have to roll your own encryption or obfuscation mechanism.

Alternatives could be obscure mechanisms (press the invisible button three times?) to send the file by email for returning the data-store to you rather than exposing the Documents folder in iTunes.

I guess the question is there a genuine need for password protection (i.e personal/medical records) or is this just the usual Corporate paranoia. If its the latter I wouldn't put too much effort in. IMHO.

Comment: more corporate paranoia - but try and explain that away.  I'll have to encode some of the more important data.  It would be just nice if there were something built in of course - anyone?

Comment: There's plenty of the usual crypto routines in the security framework that you can tap. The db would have to be plain binary at some point but it seems like you guarding against device loss here.